# Listing one element in a string[] list f#

Tags: string, list, recursion, f#, stack-overflow

I have a string[] list and I wish to group the 5th element in the string array of all the list..

I found two different ways in doing this

```
let rec Publication x y (z:string [] list) = 
    if x < z.Length then  
        let muro =  [z.[x].[y]]
        let rest = Publication (x+1) y z
        List.append muro rest     
    else  []
```

where z is the string[] list and y is the element that I wish to list. 
and

```
let Publication x (z:string [] list) = [for i in 0 .. (z.Length-1)  -> z.[i].[x]]
```

In the first case, I get a stack overflow error when working with a large set of data and the second one takes to long. Can anyone help me find a third and more eficient way? thanks!

Comment: You can convert the first one to be tail recursive (thus preventing stack usage) and simply reverse the result if you care about it being in the same order.

Comment: how can I do that? I have never understand tail recursive :(

Comment: As soon as you do, a whole new world will open for you :) It is important to understand, so try to do so. Unfortunately I dont know F# well enough to give you an answer, but the same goes for many other languages, like Scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version seems sensible on the surface, but I wonder if the problem is not the indexed access to `z`, as the list is iterated from the head for each `z.[i]` call. What I would try is plain and simple:

```
let publication idx (lst: string [] list) = 
    lst |> List.map (fun arr -> arr.[idx])
```

You have a list of arrays and an index, you go through the list and get element by the index from each array.

Comment: this works, but it takes 13 seconds to do so (same as my second option).. it takes to long to solve my problem :(

Comment: how large is your problem? try converting to an array instead of having a list.

Comment: 17800 is the size of the list. I converted it to an  Array but it only took one second less

Comment: You're spending time somewhere else. Maybe you're trying to print everything you get back? For 18.000 elements both your and my versions time under half a second for me. For 180.000, yours is 32s and mine is 3s.

Comment: how can I see where my code is using time? in visual studio

Comment: if you're using F# Interactive, `#time "on"`. If not, System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.

Comment: you can use #time;; directive in F# interactive

Comment: yep my code was wasting time in another part, thanks everyone